# Where are named pdf characters defined like "f_f", "uni00D0" and "a204"?

Tags: pdf, unicode, ascii, adobe

I'm trying to read the official pdf specification "Document management — Portable document format — Part 1: PDF 1.7" (PDF32000_2008.pdf) as bytes and then interpret them according to that specification.

In Annex D, Character Sets and Encodings, there is a list of all *named characters*, like:
[image]

or

[image]

When I parse PDF32000_2008.pdf, there are also named characters like "f_f", "uni00D0" and "a204", which are missing in that specification.

My guess is that "f_f" is a symbol for two 'f' characters, which might get printed with a special glyph. There is a unicode "Latin Small Ligature Ff" for 'ﬀ'.

For example, there is also "f_i" in that file, which I expect to mean 'ﬁ', one glyph showing the 2 characters 'f' and 'i'. However, the pdf specification has 'ﬁ' as named character "fi" and what is the point for having 2 named characters pointing to the same symbol ?

I can imagine that "uni00D0" means the unicode character 'Ð'. However, pdf defines it already as named character "Eth"

What could be "a204" ? Maybe Ansi 204 'Ì', which also has already a named character "Igrave" ?

Why do they use also "a62", which would be just a '<' ?

However, my main question is: Where can I find a specification for these additional named characters ?

Of course, Adobe Acrobat understands them, but also Gmail seems not to have a problem with them. So I guess, their meaning must be specified somewhere.

Comment: I think that you can define own character names (maybe inside the embedded font). Definitely it is a think I already noticed.

Comment: That names incosistetly resemble [html named entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) like 
 `&Aacute;&aacute;&AElig;&aelig;&mu;&micro;&eth;&ETH;&fflig;&not;`

Comment: uniXXX is for unicode, and there could be aliases. See https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-specification. The x_y is used for ligatures (pdftotext sources have a list of common one, the sources seems also to map AXX and Ann [A could be any letters])

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Thanks for the helpful link on github. There is a file which defines all A999 named characters:github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-aglfn/blob/master/zapfdingbats.txt

Comment: I actually found now also the A999 named characters in the chapter: D.6 ZapfDingbats Set and Encoding of the pdf specification.

Comment: So, now that you have all information, could you answer your question? It would help other people.

Comment: I still wonder were "f_f" and "uni00D0" are specified and if in those places even more named characters are defined. I guess you have also a point about "you can define own character names ", but I have not found it (yet) in the pdf specification. I'm rather embarrassed that I didn't notice D.6 ZapfDingbats right away and feel just that is not substantial enough as an answer. I feel your link to the files was really helpful to me and I would accept that as an answer.